# Utilizing SQL datepart to indentify consecutive periods of time

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that works correctly, but don't understand the theory behind why it works. I'm indentifying a consecutive period of time by utilizing a datepart and dense rank (found solution through help elsewhere).

```
        select 
            c.bom
            ,h.x
            ,h.z
            ,datepart(year, c.bom) * 12 + datepart(month, c.bom) -- this is returning a integer value for the year and month, allowing us to increment the number by one for each month
            - dense_rank() over ( partition by h.x order by datepart(year, c.bom) * 12 + datepart(month, c.bom)) as grp -- this row does a dense rank and subtracts out the integer date and rank so that consecutive months (ie consecutive integers) are grouped as the same integer

        from 
            #c c

            inner join test.vw_info_h h
            on h.effective_date <= c.bom
            and (h.expiration_date is null or h.expiration_date > c.bom)
```

I understand in theory what is happening with the grouping functionality.

**How does multiplying year * 12 + month work? Why do we multiply the year? What is happening in the backend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year component of a date is an integer value. Since there are 12 months in a year, multiplying the year value by 12 provides the *total* number of months that have passed to get to the first of that year.

Here's an example. Take the date February 11, 2012 (20120211 in CCYYMMDD format)

2012 * 12 = 24144 months from the start of time itself.

24144 + 2 months (february) = 24146.

Multiplying the year value by the number of months in a year allows you to establish month-related offsets without having to do any coding to handle the edge cases between the end of one year and the start of another. For example:

11/2011 -> 24143
12/2011 -> 24144
01/2012 -> 24145
02/2012 -> 24146

Comment: thank you so much for the clear explanation. I didn't even think of considering it a integer value from the start of 0 as 0 AD. Nice! Makes perfect sense now, again much appreciated.